# How to test if the user is logged in

Tags: php, session

I am fairly familiar with PHP and wanted to make a Login/Registration system, but I came across a problem with my code. I was trying to test if the user is already logged in so I can redirect them as needed, but whenever I force a login and go to the registration page it does not redirect me back as needed. Please can someone help me. Here is my code.

**Register.php**

```
<?php

        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            header('index.php');
        }
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Register Account</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css">
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class="container">
        <center><form action="#" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group top">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control width" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control width" placeholder="Enter Lastname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control width" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control width" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control width" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="register-button-validate" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
        </form></center>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `register.php` also needs this at the top:

```
session_start();
```

Basically, *any* page which writes to or reads from the session will need that.

Second, this isn't a redirect:

```
header('index.php');
```

This is:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

An incomplete header is probably just being ignored by the browser, since there's no key telling the browser what to do with that value.

Comment: Yes, this got the redirect to work, but i am still having a problem. In index.php if i do session_unset(); and try to go back to register.php i am still getting redirected back to index.php.

Comment: You should try to unset this session variable or all session variables in general. So try doing unset($_SESSION['user_id']) or unset($_SESSION) in general.